# Censoring? Am I training my model on an event that might not have happened yet?

Tags: machine-learning, censoring

I'm working on a paper at the moment, and I have gone into one of those self-doubt loops/spirals. My supervisors assure me that this is the right way, but i'm sceptical.

I am identifying doctors at risk of a negligence complaint. I have doctor demographic data and the details of the complaint. I've built out my features and have an outcome class True/False where that doctor has had a complaint or not had a complaint to train the classifiers(svm, naive bayes, cart, c5).

What is not sitting well is that i have the year the doctor came onboard, for example joined=2015. So the likelihood of a complaint for a doctor with 1 year of practice is not the same as one that has been working for 10 years.

I am worried that i am training my data on doctors that might be high risk, but they just havent had the chance to be negligent yet. So they are classed as a "False",  but give them a couple of years and they would be a "True".

My #1 question is: How do i work around this (Censoring i assume)? I know i should be deleting some of the instances where the doctors have joined recently, but Im unsure as to how to determine that cut-off?

My #2 question is: The data i have covers complaints for the last 5 years. Therefor I would have thought that my model predicts whether Doctor X is likely to committ an offense within a 5 year period. Is that the correct hypothesis?

Thanks
B

- My data:
- [Years Experiance at complaint, sum of complaints]
- [0,1]
- [1,17]
- [2,20]
- [3,14]
- [4,17]
- [5,24]
- [6,18]
- [8,22]...
- [48,1]

Mean: Average experiance at complaint 16years
StDev: 10 years experiance

Comment: So the complaint variable $y_i$ shows the number of complaints over the five year period? Is your data all cross-sectional? Or is it panel data? For doctors practicing less than 5 years, there would clearly be an issue, but for doctors practicing longer, I think you should be fine?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matthew. Yes, although it's not a numeric value, it is simply has_Offended = {True,False}.

It is cross-secctional - very broadly i got a list of doctors in one table, a list of offences in the other table, and populated the has_offended outcome as True. Thanks for the comment on the Five years, i was thinking the same. Is there technical term for this - something i can investigate further?

Comment: Sorry just clarify, the doctors have experience from 1->40+ years. I have a snapshot of complaints for 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015.

Comment: Your doubts are reasonable. Depending on the research questions, there are different less naive analysis options. Tools from duration/survival analysis to model time to complaint under censoring, count regression with log(exposure) offset or exposure weights, repeated measure logistic regression with each doctor year as a line etc.